# Is this a bug in InverseLaplaceTransform or LaplaceTransform?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

Let us consider in version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; a = InverseLaplaceTransform[s*Log[(s - 1)/(s + 1)], s, x]
```

> `(2 (-x Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]))/x^2`

and then

```
b = LaplaceTransform[a, x, s]
```

> `2 (1 - s ArcCoth[s])`

We don't come back to `s*Log[(s - 1)/(s + 1)]`.

The question arises: what  command produces an incorrect result?

Because of

```
Series[s*Log[(s - 1)/(s + 1)], {s, Infinity, 2}]
```

> $$-2-\frac{2}{3 s^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^3\right) $$

I think `InverseLaplaceTransform[s*Log[(s - 1)/(s + 1)], s, x]` does not exist as the improper integral in the definition of `InverseLaplaceTransform` likely diverges.

Comment: Are you aware of the relationship between [arcoth and log](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_cotangent)?

Comment: @Domen: Did you look at the result of `Plot[2 (1 - s ArcCoth[s]) - s*Log[(s - 1)/(s + 1)], {s, 0, 5}]` before having commented?

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounded condenscending, that was not my intention, I was just hoping it might have been the same result :) I did not plot it - I'll retract my comment

Comment: The Laplace transform of `(2 (-x Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]))/x^2` looks correct for `s > 1`, at least numerically. `In[11]:= NIntegrate[Exp[-2x](2(-x Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]))/x^2, {x, 0, ∞}] - 2(1 - 2ArcCoth[2])

Out[11]= -7.6702*10^-12`

Comment: Perhaps the problem is related to the non-uniqueness of the inverse Laplace transform for functions with discontinuities. In this case, the only difference is a constant, a 2.